# No matching signing identity found "Mac Developer:"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I am building a project downloaded from github. this project targets iphone/ipad/mac.When i build this project, it says

**No matching signing identity found** 
`No signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the value specified in your build settings, "Mac Developer:", were found. Xcode can update your build settings to their recommended values.`

When i click fix issue button it says **The selected team doesn't have a Mac Developer Program membership** `Select a team with a Mac Developer Program membership and try again`. I only have an iOS developer program membership, no mac membership. I've change the Code Signing Identity in Build Settings Tab, but the issue still exist. Can i build the project? How can i fix this issue?

Any help would be much appreciated.

screenshot of General settings in this project is as follows:
[image]

Comment: @nhgrif how to remove? i cannot find the place to remove it.

Comment: the project on the github was build with a mac developer identity. do you have one? or your cert is for just iOS development? that might be the issue. mac development and iOS development have two different membership and thus the team provisioning and certs are different.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey my cert is for just iOS. Then can i build the project by changing some settings?

Comment: It is hard to say with ought seeing the codes for the project, but it is possible by copying the classes into a new project and rebuild it for iOS if it dies not have any mac specific methods and function.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Self-Signed Codesign Certificate

It's really simple to fix this; you can create your own self-signed codesign certificate in Keychain Access. If you decide to distribute your app later, or want it to behave nicely with Gatekeeper then you'll of course need to join the Mac Developer Program.

*If it's primarily for your own usage though then you can likely choose not to codesign it at all.

> **Self-signed codesiging and No codesigning in XCode**

[image: Xcode Codesigning]

Comment: i cannot find the without codesign setting as in your screenshot. i'm using Xcode 5. i update the screenshot for mine.

Comment: `Build Settings` Tab is the same as yours.

Comment: Select either `Don't Code Sign` (Debug & Release), or create a self-signed certificate in Keychain Access. If it's an iOS and OS X app, then you should be able to add your current provisioning profile doe the iOS part. For Mac OS X you can use the methods above.

Comment: i select `Don't Code Sign` and also create a self-signed certificate.the how to use this certificate?

Comment: Put the self-signed certificate in your System Keychain, then it should show up when you're viewing the codesigning certificates in XCode. You can also sign your app from Terminal like `codesign -s (your self-signed cert name) -vvvv -f  (your app)`

Comment: i see. But the error still exist. i'm guessing i should change some setting in this project.

Answer (score 7):

Xcode Version 9.2

```
Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity -> Don't Code Sign
```

[image]

Comment: Or in "Code Signing identity" choose Sign to Run(add-Hoc signing)

Answer (score -1):

I found it to return this, i went to signing and capabilities and switched it to manual. Then it worked[image]